# Comparar a data atual com a data de vencimento e disparar um e-mail se for Expirado!! - PHP Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, comparação

Preciso fazer uma função em Javascript que caso falte 1 mês para a "validade_motorista" expirar, seja alterado o texto da tabela HTML de "Válido" para "Expirado", e que seja disparado um e-mail ao cliente informando que expirou. Tenho um básico conhecimento de PHP e consegui fazer uma simples função que adiciona 1 mês a partir da data_atual, e compara com a "validade_motorista" para definir se falta 1 mês para expirar ou ainda não, segue o código e o link funcionando para facilitar os testes:

**Link funcionando: https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/53711e5**

Clicar em "RUN" pra executar o código

Só que não faço ideia de como transformar essa função em Javascript e nem como faço para disparar um e-mail ao cliente quando o status for alterado para "Expirado" na tabela. Caso alguém souber melhor e puder ajudar ficarei grato.

```
<?php

$data_atual = '2021-02-14'; // Simula a data atual, se acrescentar uns dias vai Expirar na tabela
$validade_motorista = '14/03/2021'; // Data de validade do motorista, será salvo nesse formato no sistema

$data_atual_1mes = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($data_atual))); // Pega a "data_atual" e adiciona 1 mês

echo '<b>Data atual:</b> ' . $data_atual . '<br>';
echo '<b>Data atual + 1 mês: </b>' . $data_atual_1mes . '<br>';
echo '<b>Validade do Motorista:</b> ' . $validade_motorista . '<br><br>';

?>


<table style="text-align: center;" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Motorista</th>
      <th>Validade Motorista</th>
      <th>Status Motorista</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jonas Felipe</td>
      <td><?php echo $validade_motorista; ?></td>
      <td>
      <?php
      if ($data_atual_1mes > $validade_motorista) {
        echo '<span style="color: red;">Expirado!</span>';
      } else {
        echo '<span style="color: lime;">Válido!</span>';
      }
      ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar e-mails use a função `mail()` do php disponível [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php).
Para enviar de forma mais elaborada existe a biblioteca PHPMailer disponível [aqui](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Nos dois casos você precisará dar estudada em como utilizar os dois.

Quanto a forma de disparo o seu pensamento está na tabela e não deveria, a ação de envio de e-mail deve acontecer sempre que a página for executada, ou você precisará montar um script de rode de tempo em tempo avaliando a situação e enviando e-mails.

É muito comum  existirem rotinas no sistema, isso pode ser feito através de algum tipo de agendador de tarefas, apesar de ser o mais correto percebo que não é o que está procurando no momento.

**1º Opção**

Colocar o disparo de e-mail no prório carregamento da página, usando uma função de envio de e-mails:

```
if ($data_atual_1mes > $validade_motorista) {
  if(sendMail('email_motorista@gmail.com', 'Validade Expirada', 'Conteúdo do e-mail', null) {
    //e-mail enviado
  }
  else {
    //e-mail não enviado
  }
  echo '<span style="color: red;">Expirado!</span>';
}
```

**2º opção via AJAX**

Isto não anula a primeira opção que pode continuar sendo executada porém mais abaixo desta:

```
if($_POST['ajax']) {
  $response  = "";
  if ($data_atual_1mes > $validade_motorista) {
    if(sendMail('email_motorista@gmail.com', 'Validade Expirada', 'Conteúdo do e-mail', null) {
      //e-mail enviado
      $response = '<span style="color: red;">Expirado! Email OK</span>';
    }
    else {
      $response = '<span style="color: red;">Expirado! Email NOK</span>';
    }
    
  }
  else {
    $response = '<span style="color: lime;">Válido</span>';
  }
  //mata a execução disponibilizando a resposta
  die($response);
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)):

```
var expiraMotorista = function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'arquivo.php', //arquivo a ser executado
    type: 'POST', //ou GET
    data: {ajax: true} //parametros a serem enviados no POST/GET
  })
  .done(function(response) {
    //concluído sem erro
    //aqui seria possível atualizar a tabela com o response, usando um id <span id='situacao'>
    $("#situacao").html(response);
    console.log("sucesso");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    //falhou
    console.log("erro");
  })
  .always(function() {
    //executa sempre que concluído
    console.log("expiraMotorista() executada");
  });
}
var interval = window.setInterval('expiraMotorista()', 10000);  //10 segundos
expiraMotorista();
```

Segue uma função simples que uso para envio de e-mails utilizando o PHPMailer:

```
function sendMail($dests = null, $assunto = null, $body = null, $anexos = null) {
  global $mail_error;
  
  if($dests && $assunto) {
    //adiciona as bibliotecas
    require 'PHPMailer6/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer6/src/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer6/src/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;
    //enviar utilizando o gmail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //dados da conta, se for gmail precisa habilitar o acesso a conta
    $mail->Username = "remetente@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "senha";
    //e-mail e nome que aparecerão na caixa dod destinatario
    $mail->setFrom('remetente@gmail.com', 'Remetente');
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    //adicionando os destinarios, espera-se um array
    if(is_array($dests) && count($dests) > 0) {
      foreach($dests as $d) {
        $mail->addAddress(trim($d));
      }
      $dests = implode(",",$dests); //para reportar os e-mails no erro
    }
    else {
      if($dests) {
        $mail->addAddress(trim($dests));
      }
    }

    //adicionando os anexos, espera-se um array
    if(is_array($anexos)) {
      foreach ($anexos as $key => $anexo) {
        $mail->addStringAttachment($anexo['arquivo'], $anexo['nome_anexo'].'.pdf');
      }
    }
    else {
      if($anexos) {
        $mail->addAttachment(trim($anexos));
      }
    }

    //assunto do e-mail
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    //este e-mail pode conter conteúdo html
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    //corpo do e-mail
    $mail->Body = $body;

    //se enviado
    if ($mail->send()) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      //setar o erro na variavel global e pegar após a execução da função
      $mail_error = "Houve erro no envio do e-mail para ($dests): {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
      return false;
    }
  }
  else {
    $mail_error "Destinatário ou assunto não informado";
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado pela resposta. Tenho uma dúvida referente a sua primeira recomendação, de colocar uma função no carregamento da página, será que não seria disparado o e-mail toda vez que a página fosse carregada? Ou precisaria criar também uma função que verifica quais id's já foram enviados o e-mail e quais não...

Comment: Não falei sobre isso mesmo, mas é justo que idependente da escolha deve haver um controle de quem já teve o envio realizado, geralmente é uma tabela filha do motorista, ou uma tabela geral de controle de e-mails, ao enviar o e-mail registra ele e também guarda se houve sucesso ou erro no envio, se há um registro de envio de e-mail que obteve sucesso após a data de expiração então não é necessário um novo envio.